# Case Statement within a Where clause

Tags: sql, case

I am trying to rewrite the below query to give me top performers for the week and not the day.  Because my week runs Friday thru Sunday, I need to tell sql that if the date is x, then the week it is in is y.

Here is my working daily query:

```
SELECT u.UserName, COUNT t.Policy AS Policies, SUM t.Fee AS Premium
FROM Users u INNER JOIN PolicyInfo t ON u.UserID = t.UserID
WHERE t.Date >= convert(date,getdate()))
GROUP BY u.UserName
ORDER BY Policies desc, Premium desc
```

Here is my NON-Working weekly query:

```
SELECT u.UserName, COUNT t.Policy AS Policies, SUM t.Fee AS Premium
FROM Users u INNER JOIN PolicyInfo t ON u.UserID = t.UserID
WHERE t.Date >= convert(date,getdate()))
AND CASE DATEPART(WEEKDAY, t.Date)
    WHEN 1 THEN cast (convert(varchar (8), DATEADD(d,5,[t.Date]),112) as date)
    WHEN 2 THEN cast (convert(varchar (8), DATEADD(d,4,[t.Date]),112) as date)
    WHEN 3 THEN cast (convert(varchar (8), DATEADD(d,3,[t.Date]),112) as date)
    WHEN 4 THEN cast (convert(varchar (8), DATEADD(d,2,[t.Date]),112) as date)
    WHEN 5 THEN cast (convert(varchar (8), DATEADD(d,1,[t.Date]),112) as date)
    WHEN 6 THEN cast (convert(varchar (8), DATEADD(d,0,[t.Date]),112) as date)
    WHEN 7 THEN cast (convert(varchar (8), DATEADD(d,6,[t.Date]),112) as date)

GROUP BY u.UserName
ORDER BY Policies desc, Premium desc
```

Comment: you did not tell the case statement to `end` maybe a reason why

Comment: Are you looking for top performers of **this** week?

Comment: What DBMS are you using? SQL Server?

Comment: Following up on @MCP_Infiltrator, You also didn't tell the WHERE clause what to compare the result of the CASE statement against.  WHERE clause fragments need to evaluate as boolean.

Comment: Can you include the error you're getting?

Answer (score 0):

A simple calculation to get the first day of the current week would be:

```
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

Since you would need to determine the most recent Friday, that would need a bit of tweaking:

```
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, (12-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) % 7) - 6, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

Now that you have this, you can add this to the GROUP BY clause:

```
SELECT u.UserName, t.weekStarting, COUNT(t.Policy) AS Policies, SUM(t.Fee) AS Premium
FROM Users u 
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT *, SELECT DATEADD(DAY, (12-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, Date) % 7) - 6, Date) weekStarting
  FROM PolicyInfo) t ON u.UserID = t.UserID
WHERE t.Date >= convert(date,getdate())
GROUP BY u.UserName, t.weekStarting
ORDER BY Policies desc, Premium desc
```

Comment: When I try to use the above query using the Group By clause, I get the following errors: Incorrect syntax near the kyword SELECT and Incorrect syntax near ')'

Comment: @user3154648: Yup, I had an extra ')' in there - fixed.  Also, what DBMS are you using (e.g. MySQL, Access, SQL Server)?